# Error Exited with status code 147 on Xcode 15

Tags: xcode

I try to build my app on Xcode 15 but I got an error "Exited with status code 147".

I look on the log and found this message

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=403):
Incompatible device
Unable to create a device for device type: iPhone X (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-X), 
runtime: iOS 17.2 (17.2 - 21C62) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-2
```

Anyone already see this type of bug and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a script that was created by me a long time ago in the AppScheme and I didn't use it anymore.
Just delete it and it works now.